# Tranfser props to sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Instead of% username%, I would like the current name and name to be displayed in the modal title
user's surname. I can't make this task. I 
after solving the problem, give ideas how I can optimize my code.

**Code:**

```js
   
class App extends React.Component { 

  state= {
    show: false,
    };

    showModal = () =>{
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  };

  render() {

    const users = this.props.data.users;
    const userList = users.map(user => <User key={user.id} user={user} onOpen={this.showModal} name={user.name} surname={user.surname}/>)
 
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {userList}
        {this.state.show ? < Modal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.show}/> : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class User extends React.Component{

  onOpen = () => {
    this.props.onOpen && this.props.onOpen();
  };

  render(){

    const {avatar, name, surname, city, country} = this.props.user;

    return(
      <div className="box">
    <img src={avatar} alt="" className="avatar" />

    <h3 className="box-title">{`${name} ${surname}`}</h3>
    <p className="box-description">{`${city}, ${country}`}</p>

    <div className="button-wrap">
    <a href="#" className="button" onClick={()=> this.onOpen()} >Report user</a>
    </div>
  </div>   
    )
  }
}

class Modal extends React.Component { 

  onClose = () => {
    this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose();
  };

  render() {

    if(!this.props.show){
      return null;
  }
  
    // tak wygląda struktura HTML dla modal boxa
    return (
     <div className="modal">
         <div className="modal-background"></div>
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="box">
            <h3 className="modal-title">Report user</h3>
              <textarea rows="6"></textarea>
              
              <div className="button-wrap">
                <a href="#" className="button button-link" onClick={() => {
              this.onClose()}}>Cancel</a>
                <a href="#" className="button ml-auto" onClick={()=> alert("ok")}>Report</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: Basically what you need to do is have both components receive their name property from the same parent component. If the components can change the data, a function that changes the value itself needs to be passed down from the parent, and the parent should hold the data in the state.
That said, this isn't really how you should ask a question. You should first read up the React documentation, try your hand at doing the said task, and should come to stackoverflow with an almost-working example of the issue after you run out of ideas, https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using state `ReportUsr` to store the user you want to report changed by function `this.ReportUsr` in App class  then pass function as prop `Report` to User class to call it `OnClick` with the value `surname` for that instance of User component

then  Modal component  created from App class has CONTENT which is the App.state.ReportUsr

```
< Modal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.show} >{this.state.ReportUsr}</ Modal>
```

LiveExample
https://h4i1e.csb.app/

Code  https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-browser-h4i1e